# 200 response on Nginx 404 error page

Tags: nginx, custom-error-pages

My server uses a custom 404 page.
Is't possible to get 404 server response on a direct request of 404 page? 
Now:
URL: http://mydomain.xxx/404.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 14):

you can simply do

```
error_page 404 =200 /404.php;
```

Comment: Do I have to specify /404.php? I'd like to keep the current page but just do a 200 error.

Answer (score 0):

Serve /404.html content preserving original URL (404 status code).

```
server {
    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
        internal;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html;
    }
}
```